# Get the intersection of a polygon with a generated buffer in postgis

Tags: postgis

I have two tables. One has points in EPSG:4326 and the other one has polygons also in EPSG:4326.
I loaded these two as layers in geoserver and show them using openlayers (as shown in image)

Now I want to write a query in postgis in which I find the intersection area of each green point (buffered by 200 meters) with the polygons.

I have written this query:

```
SELECT c.name, d.name FROM points c, polygons d WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(d.geom, ST_BUFFER(c.geom,500))
```

But I get no results. If I increase the buffer size to 5000000 then I get results.

1. So the question is if there is a better way to do this without using a Buffer.
2. If there is projection issue in which I am missing.

**EDIT**

I followed the advice of @HimBromBeere and transformed my geometries to EPSG: 2100 (which is in metres). 
The problem still remains as executing this query I get as a result 0, which doesnt make any sense.

```
SELECT ST_AREA(
      ST_INTERSECTION(ST_Buffer
      (ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(c.geom, 4326),2100),200),
      ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(d.geom, 4326),2100))) 
      FROM categoriesdata c, dimoi d
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when you ommit the `ST_SetSRID`-part?

Comment: @HimBromBeere it also returns the same. A column with 0 values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ST_Buffer` will consider your spatial reference. So as you have geographic coordinates you have to provide your buffer-size in degrees as well.

Alternativly you may transform your geometries into a metric spatial-refrence first as proposed [here](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html):

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(
    ST_Transform(
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.063526, 42.35785), 4326),
        myNewReferenceSystem), 
    200); // buffer by 200m
```

Comment: Please see my edit.